# Chrome-like display of menu

Tags: android, android-layout, options-menu

I'm trying to find some information on how to create a menu that looks like the top of the menu for chrome for Android. I have tried experimenting with implementing icons for Android 4.0, but no luck. Tried googeling, but the only thing i found was an answer that said icons can't be implemented when API >= 11.

How does Chrome do it then? It's made for devices that's 4.0+!

[image]

Comment: You should save us the trouble of having to use the link and embed the image into the post.

Comment: looks like a custom view...not a api in the SDK to do something like this that I am aware of

Comment: sorry, but I don't have enough points to add picture directly.

Answer (score 2):

Use popup list window to achieve this. As you can add header and footer to any list, you can create one linear layout with back forward and star like options.. Add that view to the popup window.

Answer (score 2):

Any `ListView` can be associated with `HeaderViewListAdapter`, using this you can attach seperate layouts as a header and or footer to your listViews.

As [Vinodkumar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12085581/408150) said, you can also use `ListPopupWindow` with `HeaderViewListAdapter`s.

In the Android reference: [HeaderViewListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.html) and [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html)