# How to create custom sub menu like Google Chrome application

Tags: android, submenu

I would like to implement custom sub menu like the one Google Chrome have in the android.

[image: Screenshot of Chrome android app]

I am not sure if it is implemented using `SubMenu` or `PopupMenu`.

any guide or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome-like display of menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11908908/chrome-like-display-of-menu)

Answer (score 0):

Any `ListView` can be associated with `HeaderViewListAdapter`, using this you can attach seperate layouts as a header and or footer to your listViews. So you can have the three buttons on top as a header view, and the rest of them as normal list items. When you want to show the menu, just inflate and display this ListView over whichever part of the screen suits your needs.

You can also use `ListPopupWindow` with `HeaderViewListAdapter`s.

In the Android documentation: [HeaderViewListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.html) and [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html)

Comment: ***display this ListView over whichever part of the screen suits your needs*** how can that be done?

Comment: You can add a RelativeLayout to your screen and then pin it to whichever two corners you need dynamically.