# Position, Shadow and dismissing of PopupWindow like an Actionbar Menu [Android]

Tags: android, position, shadow, popupwindow

I am trying to create a PopupWindow that works like an Actionbar Menu like in Chrome for android - 
example:
[How to create custom sub menu like Google Chrome application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14354155/how-to-create-custom-sub-menu-like-google-chrome-application)

Here's what I have so far:
[image]

Currently - I have 3 problems:

1. I need to position the menu to the right Actionbar button, and below it. like the usual Menus..
2. I need to have a shadow on the PopupWindow (for some reason it is removed, as I know PopupWindow automatically have this shadow around it)
3. When clicking outside the PopupWindow, I need it to dismiss like the usual menus of the Actionbar..

Here's my code-
On click of the Actionbar button this is the code that runs:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.options_menu, null, false), LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
    pw.showAtLocation(findViewById(R.id.main_cont), Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 50, this.getSupportActionBar().getHeight() + 1);


    ListView moreOptions = (ListView)pw.getContentView().findViewById(R.id.moreOptions);
    String[] options = new String[] { "Settings", "Feedback", "Contribute", "DashClock Integration", "Tutorial", "ViewPager Demo", "Expandable List Demo", "Change Language", "Add 5 to list", "Add 20 to list" };

    final ArrayList<String> moreOptionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < options.length; ++i) {
        moreOptionsList.add(options[i]);
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> moreOptionsAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            moreOptionsList);
    moreOptions.setAdapter(moreOptionsAdapter);


    //pw.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.listview_bg_inverted));
    /*
    pw.setTouchable(true);
    pw.setFocusable(false);
    */
    pw.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

Design of the menu:
http://pastebin.com/yi6S2HDt

Thanks in advanced,
Din.

Answer (score 0):

The `PopupWindow` has a background (you can change it easily) but no shadow by itself.

The `showAtLocation()` you actually use allows you to specify the exact position where the window would appear.

To make it dismiss automatically, just call `setOutsideTouchable(true);` in the constructor.

But having said all that, wouldn't it be better to use a `PopupMenu` instead of a `PopupWindow`?